# Burst Power +2 because of Cone Template?

Tags: spells, savage-worlds, powers

In the core rules of the deluxe version it is mentioned that a flamethrower gets +2 to hit since its failry easy for this kind of weapon.

But what about the **Burst** power?
It uses the cone template and same damage as a flamethrower i think. So does the spellcaster get +2 on his arcane skill or not?

Does it only do the +2 if the trapping is fire?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. The roll for the flamethrower is to correctly *direct* and to *operate* it. Both of these things are easy, and so you get a bonus when using it.

The roll for the spell is to correctly *direct* and *cast* it. Casting magic is not especially easy, and there is no reason to believe that a **Burst** is an easier spell to aim than any other. And being a spell, aiming it right is more part of casting it right, not just pointing your finger accurately. This all makes successfully using a **Burst** rather unlike successfully using a flamethrower, and doesn't really support giving spellcasters a big +2 bonus for free.

Comment: So that there is no confusion, this answer uses the word "aim" to mean the general process of pointing at the target, rather than the Aim combat maneuver. Also, the Aim combat maneuver only gives a +2 bonus to Shooting rolls, not arcane skill rolls.

Comment: @Thunderforge Good catch. I started to fix that with a footnote, and then just decided changing the word to "direct" was simpler and cleaner. Thanks!